# How can i release checked out files locally in perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am new to perforce. I need clarification on the below.

I have created workspace and by mistake i have checked out the entire project(all files). I have not done any changes in the local workspace. After some days i tried to get latest revision from the server it shows some merger conflict error.

Now, How can i release the checked out files without affecting remote files. Will it affect remote files if i do revert operation locally.

Thanks for your kind advice.
Selva

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't made any changes then simply reverting the checkout will "release the checked out files". This will not affect any files checked out or modified elsewhere as it is simply an operation that works on your copies of the files.

Any operation you can do will only affect your local copies and the files in the depot. You cannot directly affect files on other people's machines.

Comment: Thanks ChrisF for your valuable answer.

Comment: if you can see it, why can't the OP?

Comment: @eeerahul - because I got notified via the inbox, but the OP doesn't.